# Мне нужно, используя язык python, вывести в одну строчку цифры, чтобы по итогу получилось так: 0 1 2

Tags: python, массивы

Имеются массивы, отображающие цифры:

```
Zero  = 
   [" *** ", 
    "*   *", 
    "*   *", 
    "*   *",
    "*   *",
    "*   *",
    " *** "]

One   = 
   [" * ",
    "** ",
    " * ",
    " * ",
    " * ",
    " * ",
    "***"]

Two   = 
   [" *** ",
    "*   *",
    "*  * ",
    "  *  ",
    " *   ",
    "*    ",
    "*****"]
```

Comment: Какие ваши мысли на этот счет?

Comment: Советую не называть переменные с большой буквы, так [принято](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) именовать классы. Используйте `snake_case` вместо этого.

Answer (score 7):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
for row in zip(Zero, One, Two):
    print(*row)
```

***stdout:***

```html
 ***   *   *** 
*   * **  *   *
*   *  *  *  * 
*   *  *    *  
*   *  *   *   
*   *  *  *    
 ***  *** *****
```

---

> **zip**(**iterables*)
> Создаёт итератор, который объединяет элементы из каждого
> итерируемого объекта.
>
> Возвращает итератор кортежей, где i-тый кортеж содержит i-тый
> элемент из каждой последовательности.

<sup>*Вольный перевод отрывка из документации.*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Просто выводите в одной строке каждый элемент списка

```
for i in range(len(Zero)):
    print(Zero[i], One[i], Two[i])
```

Результат:

```
 ***   *   *** 
*   * **  *   *
*   *  *  *  * 
*   *  *    *  
*   *  *   *   
*   *  *  *    
 ***  *** *****
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что нужно)

Comment: Но с `zip` вы обойдете ошибку, которая возникнет, если размеры списков будут разные.

Comment: @ioprst Ошибки с `zip` не будет, но он зато обрежет остальные коллекции по размеру минимальной из них, что тоже не очень хорошо будет выглядеть )