# Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы весь текст в cmd выводился на одном уровне?

Tags: python

Здраствуйте, у меня есть проблем.
Мне надо вывести огромные в cmd типа этого:

```
░░███╗░░
░████║░░
██╔██║░░
╚═╝██║░░
███████╗
╚══════╝
```

Но проблема в том что при выполнение одного условия, вторая цифра должна напечататься рядом
(Я делаю загрузку из таких цифр)
Вот так:

```
░░███╗░  ░██████╗░
░████║░ ░╚════██╗
██╔██║░ ░░░███╔═╝
╚═╝██║░ ░██╔══╝░░
███████╗ ███████╗
╚══════╝ ╚══════╝
```

Но как это сделать? Стандартные команды не помогают и вообще **возможно ли это**?
Кстати вот сам массив:

```
NUMBERS = [
"""
░█████╗░
██╔══██╗
██║░░██║
██║░░██║
╚█████╔╝
░╚════╝░""",
"""
░░███╗░░
░████║░░
██╔██║░░
╚═╝██║░░
███████╗
╚══════╝""",
"""
██████╗░
╚════██╗
░░███╔═╝
██╔══╝░░
███████╗
╚══════╝""",
"""
██████╗░
╚════██╗
░█████╔╝
░╚═══██╗
██████╔╝
╚═════╝░""",
"""
░░██╗██╗
░██╔╝██║
██╔╝░██║
███████║
╚════██║
░░░░░╚═╝""",
"""
███████╗
██╔════╝
██████╗░
╚════██╗
██████╔╝
╚═════╝░""",
"""
░█████╗░
██╔═══╝░
██████╗░
██╔══██╗
╚█████╔╝
░╚════╝░""",
"""
███████╗
╚════██║
░░░░██╔╝
░░░██╔╝░
░░██╔╝░░
░░╚═╝░░░""",
"""
░█████╗░
██╔══██╗
╚█████╔╝
██╔══██╗
╚█████╔╝
░╚════╝░""",
"""
░█████╗░
██╔══██╗
╚██████║
░╚═══██║
░█████╔╝
░╚════╝░"""]
```

Отличается от другого вопроса он тем что тут нельзя применить zip. Даже если сделать такие условия то это будет долго и не факт что будет работать.

Comment: Насчёт кода, не вижу смысла прикреплять как я пытаюсь это сделать через str.replase, str.strip() и тд

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Мне нужно, используя язык python, вывести в одну строчку цифры, чтобы по итогу получилось так: 0 1 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1244621/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf)

Comment: @Kers а как мне поможет zip в моём случае. У меня все 9 цифр в одном массиве.

Comment: @ІванШнір Храните цифру в виде массива строк, а не одной строки.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Это легко решается через `split` )

Comment: Возможно я не правильно задал свой вопрос. Простите

Comment: @ІванШнір все приводится в необходимый вид.. ниже уже даже ответ написали через zip

Comment: @ІванШнір Вы только вопрос не удаляйте, вдруг мой ответ кому ещё пригодится )  Хотя не знаю, может и правда полный дубликат к тому, что уже есть, но это модераторам решать. А то обидно бывает - пишешь ответ, а автор вопрос удаляет )

Comment: Та конечно не буду. Я ценю ваши старания и верю что он мне поможет , просто я криворукий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну почему же `zip` то нельзя:

```
for t in zip(*map(str.split, NUMBERS)):
    print(*t)
```

Вывод:

```
░█████╗░ ░░███╗░░ ██████╗░ ██████╗░ ░░██╗██╗ ███████╗ ░█████╗░ ███████╗ ░█████╗░ ░█████╗░
██╔══██╗ ░████║░░ ╚════██╗ ╚════██╗ ░██╔╝██║ ██╔════╝ ██╔═══╝░ ╚════██║ ██╔══██╗ ██╔══██╗
██║░░██║ ██╔██║░░ ░░███╔═╝ ░█████╔╝ ██╔╝░██║ ██████╗░ ██████╗░ ░░░░██╔╝ ╚█████╔╝ ╚██████║
██║░░██║ ╚═╝██║░░ ██╔══╝░░ ░╚═══██╗ ███████║ ╚════██╗ ██╔══██╗ ░░░██╔╝░ ██╔══██╗ ░╚═══██║
╚█████╔╝ ███████╗ ███████╗ ██████╔╝ ╚════██║ ██████╔╝ ╚█████╔╝ ░░██╔╝░░ ╚█████╔╝ ░█████╔╝
░╚════╝░ ╚══════╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═════╝░ ░░░░░╚═╝ ╚═════╝░ ░╚════╝░ ░░╚═╝░░░ ░╚════╝░ ░╚════╝░
```

Печать цифр на выбор, а не всего набора:

```
for t in zip(*map(str.split, [NUMBERS[int(i)] for i in "42"])):
    print(*t)
```

Вывод:

```
░░██╗██╗ ██████╗░
░██╔╝██║ ╚════██╗
██╔╝░██║ ░░███╔═╝
███████║ ██╔══╝░░
╚════██║ ███████╗
░░░░░╚═╝ ╚══════╝
```

Comment: Да, вы били правы. Просто мне надо было додумать как это правильно реализовать. Простите за моё упёрство что zip не поможет (Мало работаю с строками )

Comment: @ІванШнір Ничего, опыт дело наживное. Со временем нарабатываются готовые рецепты и проще становится.